# sorting with qsort in c

Tags: c, generics, pointers

I have 2 questions. One about realloc and one about sorting with qsort. In the following code of mine I keep crashing for "temp=realloc(input,(i+1)*sizeof(int));", but everything works fine for "i+2". Why? :/
I put integers in the array until an integer "<0" is entered. Then I print some addresses.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int *input,*temp,*f,*l;
        input=malloc(sizeof(int));
        int x,i,counter;
        counter=0;
        i=0;
        while (x>=0)
        {
            scanf("%d",&x);
            if(x<0) break;
            input[i]=x;
            temp=realloc(input,(i+2)*sizeof(int));
            counter++;
            i++;
            if (temp!=NULL) input=temp;
            else
            {
                    free(input);
                    printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    for(i=0; i<counter; i++) printf("Input: %d",input[i]);
    printf("table address: %p",&input);
    printf("first element address: %p",&input[0]);
    printf("last element address: %p",&input[counter-1]);
    }
```

About sorting this array with qsort. I found this code as an example in "cplusplus.com":

```
    /* qsort example */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

    int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
    }

    int main ()
    {
        int n;
        qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
        for (n=0; n<6; n++)
        printf ("%d ",values[n]);
        return 0;
    }
```

I can't understand how are the pointers a and b connected to the array of the example. If I want to use a different sorting algorithm, or sort from bigger to smaller should I change "return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );"??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are two separate topics, and so should be asked as two separate Stack Overflow questions...

Comment: ah sorry, didn't know that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use `realloc` here. You know what is the size of table, it's `x`. So allocate at first table of length `x`, with `malloc`. Also, `for` loop is more suitable here, not `while`. Just a stylistic improvement.
2. Yes you change that part, it should be `( *(int*)b - *(int*)a )` to sort from bigger to smaller.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll check the source code of qsort to find out about the pointers. About realloc, I tried different things.. seems like I must finally learn to use a debugger to find out some things about memory!!

Comment: The array is not of length x. The array is of dynamic length. It stores all the integers "x" until the user presses an integer smaller than 0!!! Sorry for not puting comments there...